# Mail gets send from smtp username setting not from "from" method in ActionMailer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

In user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "email.1@gmail.com"
  def approved_mail(user)
    @user = user
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: @user.email
  end
end
```

And in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "email.2@gmail.com",
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

I get email from "email.2@gmail.com" why not from "email.1@gmail.com", waiting for clarification guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `smtp_settings`, we need to set the `user_name` and `password` if our mail server requires authentication.

In your case you have provided the authentication for `'email.2@gmail.com'` in development.rb file. Hence action mailer will ignore `default from: "email.1@gmail.com"` as it cannot authenticate it.

Comment: means, 'from' default option in user_mailer.rb and 'smtp_settings > user_name' should be same - is my comment true or I'm lacking sufficient understanding

Answer (score 1):

`user_name` in the `smtp_settings` only refers to the authentication name used to connect to the SMTP server.

Add this to your `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: "email.2@gmail.com" }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I should have received email from address specified in user_mailer.rb, so I want to know why line 'default from: "email.1@gmail.com"' in user_mailer.rb not working.